# Micro-controller failure problem as the temperature raises

Tags: microcontroller, frequency, temperature, failure

I'm using at91sam3s8b(cortex-M3) for my project.The hardware board connects to PC using USB port. The firmware contains some cryptographic algorithms (it includes shifts, Xors, memory substitution operations). The algorithm output is correct when the board is powered on but it starts to fail as time passes.

The master clock is configured at maximum (64 MHz).

my observations are:

1. if I lower the MCK frequency the failure rate decreases. (it's not related to the frequency decrease rate. The failure completely fades if I use a frequency of 55 MHz)
2. If I raise the board temperature the failure happens sooner and if I lower the temperature enough the failure fades again!
3. Some micro-controllers fail (the most of them). but some others do not. (even at an artificial temperature of 85 degrees of centigrade)

The malfunctioning boards and hardware are sent to Atmel for test. they conducted a few electrical tests and answered there is no problem relating to our board or their micro-controllers.

Any idea how or where I can track this Issue? Any technical suggestion?

Edit:

More information:

- The project is being built using keil 4.7
- The cryptographic routines are implemented in assembly and c and are linked to the main project as static libraries (there is 2 separate libraries. assembly is built using code sourcery).
- changing the order of libraries in the project displaces the fault to another algorithm. changing the name, place or declarations of some functions removes or displaces the fault.
- The hardware board is simple. a microcontroller, a USB port and a SPI flash memory(winbond serial nand flash) + that little LED. The USB port and  SPI flash are not used in the simplified test code which is still faulty.

Comment: Sounds like process variation is causing varying results. I'd say test a bunch of them at 85C at 55MHz and if you don't get any failures call it a day!

Comment: Otherwise you could monitor die temperature and scale back the function with temperature, if that is acceptable behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these solutions are acceptable. Since the frequency affects the performance directly and there is no reasonable conclusion that stops me (my project owner) from using the maximum frequency. and as for 'scaling the function with the temperature' I simply don't understand you. In any case I rather having some technical suggestions on how two find the failure cause and solve it.

Comment: Well, if Atmel thinks you don't have a problem, you're probably not going to find someone here who can let you into secrets of the universe... You're probably exceeding the maximum allowed die temperature or something. Modern processors often dial back their operating frequency when they are under light load to save energy and also at high temperatures to prevent data errors and damage to the chip.

Comment: At process corner (maximum temperature, minimum instruction cycle time) some internal step within the algorithm is not available within allowed time. If issue is not caused by hardware it could be caused by a **race condition** (design flaw in algorithm). As a diagnostic, can you try inserting delays at strategic points, such as when writing and them reading results from memory. This emulates the same effect as slowing the master clock, but if proven effective, you can fine-tune where the sync delays are required and omit them where not required.

Comment: Are you sure the wait states for the internal flash, and for any external memory, are set correctly for your operating frequency? What's the symptom of the failure?

Comment: @MarkU Since the algorithm executes in a single thread and interacts with no peripheral, the only possible race condition here is the race between instruction fetch and instruction execution time which is considered in **Flash Wait State** parameter. As datasheet implies using a FWS = 3 allows the microcontroller to be used at 64MHz core clock safely and this is the value I've configured. I even tried using a higher wait state. but still no luck. And as for inserting  delays, keep in mind that the processor only interacts with its flash which should be safe considering what I said above.

Comment: I simplified my code to a simple test code. there is no interaction with USB or any other external device. instead of a LED which is turned on in case the failure is detected

Comment: @pericynthion, As I answered to mark, yes. I am sure the wait state is configured correctly. The failure symptom is the wrong output of the cryptographic algorithm. As I said, I produced a simplified test code. the test code keeps computing the encrypted value for a specific plain value, then comparing it too the expected value, in a loop. all values are hard-coded and there is no input from any external source. at first the comparison is successful. But as the time passes it fails and the LED is turned on as an indicator

Comment: Can you reproduce the failure (with the LED testcase) on an Atmel supplied dev board? If you can, then you have something you can throw over the wall for them to look at. If you can't, then it's time to identify what's different between the boards.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, I've sent the hardware to Atmel and they've already approved my board. I don't have an Atmel supplied dev board. I've produced a board myself. both dev board and the product board fail as described

Comment: @Taheri : yes but clearly they missed something! If it fails on **their own board** they must escalate as a matter of urgency. And if it doesn't, you have a way forward. Personally I'd be looking at the TI Hercules as an alternative. (Mention that to the Atmel rep and watch his face).

Comment: @BrianDrummond, yes it worth trying their's. I will order one and try it. but it takes a considerable amount of time. Any other idea? I'd be glad to read

Comment: So, what is the specified maximum clock rate of the chip? At what Vcc? At what temperature? How much power does it dissipate? What voltage are you actually feeding it? Is Vcc clean? How hot does the chip get? How are you cooling it? What is your ambient temperature?

Comment: @marcelm, Maximum mck = 64 MHz no voltage or temperature consideration is specified for maximum clock. max temperature = 85 degrees of centigrade. the voltage it uses is 1.8v. vcc used is the output of a regulator converting USB 5v to 1.8. the chip gets hot up to 40-50 degrees. the operational temperature is <85. no need to cool it then. ambient temperature is <35. I've already considered and checked all of these.

Comment: @Taheri - I'm going to write a very long comment in the answer section, but one clarification needed. You said: "The algorithm output is correct when the board is powered on". How long does a board, which you know can "fail", run and produce the correct results before "failing" when (a) starting from room temperature and (b) after it has got hot, "failed" and is briefly power-cycled, and starts producing the correct result for a while (since you said that "The algorithm output is correct when the board is powered on"). I am expecting that (b) is a much shorter time than (a) - but is it?

Comment: @SamGibson, yes (b) is shorter. a warmer board fails sooner no matter how you raise the temperature.

Comment: @Taheri - thanks for the updates & edit. I'll review and comment if I can. Two more questions: (1) How are you programming the MCU at the moment, and has that choice always been true or have other techniques been used at different times? (2) For a board which is known to "fail" when hot, what are some typical times (a) [time to fail starting at room temp] and (b) [time to fail when already at failing temp] from my comment above; and what variation do you see from those typical times - for example is time (b) typical 5 mins +/- 1min or +/- 1 hour. I'm trying to understand the reproducibility.

Comment: @SamGibson, (1)we program over USB using SAM-BA(Available on ROM). This was on the use from the start. but as you might know setting the MCU to boot from ROM can't be done over USB normally. we've embedded some circuitry to be able to perform the required signaling over USB using a specific hardware. (2)this is different for MCUs and tightly depends on the ambient temperature (if I put my finger on the faulty MCU while testing the failure won't happen. My analysis is my finger syncs the heat). (a)5 mins +/- 1H on different MCUs but almost the same for the same MCU. (b) 0 +/- 1 min

Comment: @Taheri: May I please have your email address ?

Answer (score 4):

@Taheri - This is not an answer, but it would need 6+(?) comments due to space limits and unfortunately comments can't have blank lines for separation of the various points. So please just treat this as a comment giving suggestions, with better formatting and more detail :-)

---

From experience, *much* more detail (some likely under NDA) would be needed by us remote readers to *efficiently* troubleshoot this problem on your boards, making it difficult to achieve this via remote help. The suggestion from @BrianDrummond to eliminate your hardware by using an Atmel-approved board, is a good one (+1). I have seen similar problems due to system design mistakes, nothing to do with the MCU, which Brian's suggestion should help to eliminate.

There are some standard troubleshooting approaches which either haven't been mentioned, or haven't been concluded - here is a brief, non-exhaustive, list:

(a) Simplify the code further; it seems you've done more of this than mentioned in the original question, but yet more can be done to identify *exactly* where in your algorithm, the incorrect result starts. Keep reducing the amount of code and inserting fixed data values, until you cannot remove any more code without the problem "disappearing". Then look at the remaining "minimal" code.

What is unusual about that *specific* "failing" code, which could explain why you are seeing incorrect behaviour, but most other users of the same chip are not (otherwise, if this was easy to trigger, we would likely be flooded with people reporting it) e.g. are you using an unusual peripheral, like the CRC calculation unit, which many other people won't use in their designs? What else are you doing differently, which could explain why *you* are triggering this issue, yet the other thousands of similar MCUs aren't failing in the same way?

(b) Don't accept that the data at some point during your algorithm is just wrong (from code calculation? or read from RAM? or something else? it's difficult to give more precise suggestions without seeing your code...).  Instead identify exactly *how* it is wrong, by comparing the actual and the expected values at each point (bit shift? bit flip? faulty addition result? etc), and look for consistency (or lack of consistency) on the same board and across boards. Then focus on finding similarities / differences between the groups of similarly affected and similarly unaffected boards.  This specific data can help, among other potential uses, to see whether your code and observed behaviour matches with any Errata from Atmel.

(c) What is the history of this project? When did you first notice this behaviour? If previous prototypes were not affected, what is different with those, compared to the "failing" boards you are asking for help with?

(d) Consider other drastic changes e.g. running the code from RAM instead of from Flash (assuming you have a JTAG port to be able to do this more easily). If the same incorrect runtime behaviour is still observed when running from RAM as when running from Flash, then this eliminates a hypothesis of timing problems when reading from Flash (doesn't it?) and that will be one step closer to finding the root cause.

Edit:
(e) Have you tried transplanting an MCU from a "failing" board onto a "non-failing" board, to see if the problem moves with the MCU or stays with the PCB and the other components on it?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks sam for the detailed description. I've read it thoroughly. many of them are done already. But I will surely try the rest. next comment comes with some answers. and more information comes in the Edit section of the question.

Comment: (a) is done. until any change will remove the error. but that was not a specific change. Almost any change would remove or maybe displace the failure point. (b) is done. but not completely the same way you explained. the failing value had a lot of zeroes as I remember. I agree, it worth working more. But what is obvious to me is the algorithm code is not faulty. since the fault can be displaced to other algorithm or logical codes.

Comment: (c) The big remarkable history of the project is migration from SAM7 series to SAM3 series. this is where the failure appeared which we found out later! There exist a lot of more feature implementations that can't be treated 'not related' blindly. But it is clearly obvious that the SAM3 port of the project is faulty.

Comment: (d) running the code from RAM is interesting. How does it concern having a jtag port? can you explain? I think it is sufficient to just mark the code modules to load in ram in the Keil IDE.

Comment: (e) is done. the problem moves with the microcontroller

Comment: just checked on Atmel evaluation kit. SAM3S-EK and SAM3S-EK2 use SAM3s4C and SAM3sD8B both 100 PIN package. mine is a 64-package SAM3s8B.

Comment: Re point (a) - Interesting. Impossible for me to give specific suggestions without having the code and hardware in front of me, but my general approach would be "don't worry about the _exact_ failure, just minimise the code for _a_ failure". So if removing a library (as mentioned in your edit to the question) moves the location of the "failure", then temporarily accept that new definition of "failure" is seen in code X instead of code Y, and be happy that you have eliminated that library code from the investigation. :-) I would also be looking for patterns the locations of the failures.

Comment: Re point (b) - It seems further work can be done on that. "But what is obvious to me is the algorithm code is not faulty. since the fault can be displaced to other algorithm or logical codes." You could be correct about your code, but unfortunately that behaviour isn't proof that the algorithm is OK. There are types of software bugs which can also cause that behaviour (e.g. uninitialised memory, array overflows etc.), where changing the order of variables in memory etc. affects where the "failure" appears. I have diagnosed some similar problems by spotting patterns in the incorrect data. [...]

Comment: [Re point (b) cont.] [...] Even if yours is an MCU problem, I would still approach the troubleshooting assuming there is value in looking for a pattern in the _specifics_ of failures, or in the steps which trigger the problem, until proven otherwise. I have solved too many problems by identifying such patterns, to approach problems any other way :-)

Comment: Re point (d) - "running the code from RAM is interesting. How does it concern having a jtag port?" How else will you get the code into the MCU, without using a bootloader running from Flash, where there is a hypothesis that Flash may be part of the problem - see what I mean? If you have another method to get code which you are _confident_ is correct into the RAM, then good! Note: There was an early errata on the SAM3S involving _in-application_ programming of the Flash, causing possible corruption of the code being written into the Flash :-(

Comment: @Taheri - "Atmel evaluation kit. SAM3S-EK and SAM3S-EK2 use SAM3s4C and SAM3sD8B both 100 PIN package. mine is a 64-package SAM3s8B." The most similar (i.e. same non-dual bank Flash) seems to be the SAM3S4C - it has 256kB Flash instead of yours having 512kB. Unless your test code is very long, I hope that won't be a problem - and this is another reason to reduce the amount of code :-) So personally I would choose that one, but your reply to the decoupling question from Charlie, raises potential concerns in that area of your design, which could be investigated while waiting for that Eval Kit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37610/discussion-between-taheri-and-samgibson).

Answer (score 2):

Just some thoughts (can't comment, insufficient rep, sorry)

Have you looked at the regulator temp? If it hits its overheat limit it can shut down just enough to cause glitches. This could be worse for weaker microcontrollers.

5v to 1.8v = 3.2V and ??? amps = ??? watts. This will be dissipated in the regulator as heat. Also it will increase as frequency is increased, since current consumption also increases with frequency.

Lastly, I didn't see mention of how you're decoupling the supply to the microcontroller, if at all.

Low ESR ceramic cap right next to the microcontroller, right?

**Edit:** Let me clarify this last statement. There should probably be no less than three (3) decoupling capacitors in this.

1. On the regulator input/ground.
2. On the regulator output/ground.
3. On the MCU Vdd/Vss.

Number 3 is the one that is most often forgotten. All of these should be low ESR, and low inductance capacitors; self resonant frequencies much greater than 10Mhz. And every single one should be as close to their respective part as engineering will allow.

Don't forget that the MCU also probably has it's own regulator built in, and that will need decoupling. Some MCUs even break their internal regulator out (Vusb pin?) and you will need to decouple this explicitly as well.

Comment: Thanks for the information charlie. I will check on these and answer soon

Comment: the requlator converts 5v to 3.3. I was wrong back there when I said it converts to 1.8. The regulator is a TI LP2980. As the datasheet imlpies it has a -40to 125 operational voltage which in my case is surely met. Although as the datasheet states. we use a 2.2 microF tantalum capacitor which is the most recommended one. (right next to microcontroller)

Comment: @Taheri - "right next to microcontroller" Actually the output cap of an LDO voltage regulator needs to be right next to the _regulator_ - otherwise the regulator output loop includes the inductance and resistance of the PCB up to that cap. This can risk lack of stability under transient load conditions, amongst other problems. Some LDO datasheets make the point clearer, but see page 20 of the datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp2980-n.pdf "For best overall performance, **place all circuit components** [...] **as near as practical to the respective LDO pin connections**." [...]

Comment: [...] Place **ground return connections to the** input and **output capacitors, and to the LDO ground pin as close to each other as possible**, connected by a wide, component-side, copper surface." [my bold] You then need _additional_ decoupling next to the MCU, of course. So perhaps the point made by @Charlie is still worth considering?

Comment: Taheri - I think it's worth pointing out that if there is anything "wrong" (out-of-spec) with the power to the MCUs (or any other datasheet value), then just because you see some MCUs "failing" does _not_ mean they are faulty! As soon as you have an out-of-spec condition, then all bets are off! The fact that some of your MCUs seem to behave OK when hot could mean that they are _better_ than they have to be, not that the failing ones are _worse_. This is where testing with an Atmel-designed board as suggested earlier by @BrianDrummond has real value _if_ your problem can be reproduced there.

Comment: Woo, I can comment now!

@SamGibson - Just to acknowledge your comments; you are correct on the decoupling cap issue. I have edited my answer to reflect your input. You are also correct on the out-of-spec condition. As you said, all bets are off if anything goes out of spec. I feel this needs to be eliminated first before we can move forward.

Taheri - I agree with BrianDrummond and SamGibson, you really need to test in a factory board if you can at all help it. These boards will be thoroughly tested by a large community, 
which will eliminate that as a variable and give you valuable incite.

Comment: @Charlie, This needs proper checking with my partner(he does the hardware stuff). will be done. Thanks. I will post the feedback